# Spring batch job status FAILED when all Steps COMPLETED

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which uses flow:

```
  Flow productFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("productFlow")
                .start(productFlow)
                .next(new MyDecider()).on("YES").to(anotherFlow)
                .build();
```

After I started to use a decider which checks some value in Jobparameter from job execution to decide whether to run the next flow or not, I am no lo longer getting COMPLETED as overall job status in JobExecution. It comes as FAILED.

However, every step in the STEP EXECUTION Table are COMPLETED and none FAILED.

Have I missed a trick somewhere?

My Decider is looks like this:

```
public class AnotherFlowDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

    @Override
    public AnotherFlowDecider decide(final JobExecution jobExecution, final StepExecution stepExecution) {

        final JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();

        final String name = jobParameters.getString("name");

        if (nonNull(name)) {

            switch (name) {
                case "A":
                    return new FlowExecutionStatus("YES");
                case "B":
                default:
                    return new FlowExecutionStatus("NO");
            }

        }

        throw new MyCustomException(FAULT, "nameis not provided as a JobParameter");
    }
}
```

in Debug mode I can see

```
2020-12-11 11:10:58.145 DEBUG [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.b.c.j.f.s.SimpleFlow [eId=, rId=] -- Completed state=productFlow.stageProduct with status=COMPLETED
2020-12-11 11:10:58.146 DEBUG [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.b.c.j.f.s.SimpleFlow [eId=, rId=] -- Handling state=productFlow.decision0
2020-12-11 11:10:58.146 DEBUG [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.b.c.j.f.s.SimpleFlow [eId=, rId=] -- Completed state=productFlow.decision0 with status=NO
2020-12-11 11:10:58.146 DEBUG [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.b.c.j.f.s.SimpleFlow [eId=, rId=] -- Handling state=productFlow.FAILED
```

Comment: added more clarity

Comment: Do you see any errors in the debug log? Your flow definition is incomplete: you specified the outgoing transition from the decider on `YES`, but you did not specify the outcome for other cases. You should add something like: `.on("*").end()` or similar.

Comment: `.from(new AnotherFlowDecider()).on("NO").end()` ? Something like this ?

Comment: Yes, for example. You should make sure your flow definition is complete (ie, all outgoing possible transitions from the decider are defined).

Comment: Ok, this didn't fix the issue. So I will check the debug logs. JobExecution has no exit message but status is FAILED as well similar to Step tables.

Comment: not seeing anything useful in the logs to indicate exact issue. I added logs to my question. Any ideas ?

Comment: seems the issue was it wasnt liking the `new AnotherFlowDecider ()`. I defined the decider as a bean in Job Config class and used it as `next(decider()..`) that works :)